# Reversed numbering parentheses for alignat env in RTL context (lualatex)

Tags: luatex, amsmath, babel, right-to-left

With this example of `alignat` environement parentheses of numbering are reversed, on the contrary parentheses in `align` environment are fine

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& u=\arctan{x}       &\qquad& v=x\\
& du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &&       dv=1
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
 u&=\arctan{x}   \\
 du&=\frac{1}{1+x^2} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I tried to test  the text direction by adding  `\the\textdirection` within  `\maketag@@@` command which hold equation numbering

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\the\textdirection\m@th\normalfont#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{alignat}{2}
& u=\arctan{x}       &\qquad& v=x\\
& du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &&       dv=1
\end{alignat}


\begin{align}
 u&=\arctan{x}   \\
 du&=\frac{1}{1+x^2} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My question is why nembering of `alignat` are in TLT text direction unlike numbering in `align` environment?

**Remark**

The problem does not occur if we do not use  `babel` package just like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\pardir TRT \textdir TRT
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
& u=\arctan{x}       &\qquad& v=x\\
& du=\frac{1}{1+x^2} &&       dv=1
\end{alignat}

\begin{align}
 u&=\arctan{x}   \\
 du&=\frac{1}{1+x^2} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a workaround use the Harfbuzz renderer. It seems `alignat` is not correctly patched. Note inside maths the direction is reset to `\mathdir`, which means in your last example the text and par dirs are TLT.